# How to pass Json array from a controller to Javascript (ajax) in view.cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass a array of Document objects from a method (let's say from a controller) to the JavaScript from which the method is called (in a view). For some reason, the method won't pass the array (it works only if the array is empty). I also tried to put all the array members into a new array, even a list and pass it to the view, but it won't work (Inspect Element -> Console = 500 (Internal Server Error))
([Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPNa4.png)).

Here is a part of the JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
            method:"get",
            data: data,
            url: url + "?binderId=" + companyId +"&description="+ data

        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(response);

        }).error(function (response) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Here is the C# code, sending the array to the JavaScript from above:

```
 public ActionResult SearchDocument(int binderId, string description)
    {
        //documents is a array
        var documents = Search.SearchDocument(binderId, description);
        return Json(documents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I think that somethings wrong with the JavaScript, but I don't know what. 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you setting 'dataType' and 'contentType' ajax properties, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I did that and nothing changes. It works fine when receiving only one object, but fails when receiving an array.

Comment: Did you debug the Controller code, to certify that documents variable is an array with data? try to put a ````debugger;```` into your ````success```` callback

Comment: I just noticed the internal server error thing, sorry.  The problem is in the Controller Action.  Can you post the code for Search.SearchDocument?  What is that returning?

Comment: Here is it. SearchDocument receives an array, and that's fine, but something between the SearchDocument method and the JS goes wrong... 


    public static List<Document> SearchDocument(int binderId, string documentDescription)
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var documents = db.Documents.Where(x => x.BinderId == binderId && x.DocumentDescription.Contains(documentDescription)).ToList();
                return documents;
            }
        }

Comment: Note that your JS code looks wrong - for GET `data` is added as query parameters - so check how final url look like.

Comment: @PedroBenevides it goes straight to the error callback part.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it doesn't matter, when I put a breakpoint in the method, it works just fine.

Comment: @LazarZoltan then you are having problems in your Controller Class, try to debug the complete flow, including some ActionFilter you might have

Comment: @LazarZoltan any luck?

Comment: @PedroBenevides unfortunately no. Could it be because of the Binder, Company and DocumentType properties? They are throwing exceptions. Check out the link (it's a screenshot)
[link](http://postimg.org/image/ys7lnz8zp/)

Comment: @PedroBenevides, I solved it. Still don't know what's the problem, but I assume the properties I mention above were causing the problem. Here is my solution. I created a new class, witch has only the properties I need. I copied the data from the "original" object to the new one, so it has no properties (data) from any other table from the db. In the end, I have a pure object with no references of any other table and i put the object(s) into a list. Now, it can be sent to the JavaScript in the view.

However, thank you all very much for trying to help! You guys are the best!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try returning JsonResult instead of ActionResult

public JsonResult SearchDocument(int binderId, string description)

Comment: Tried it, same result.